# vertical-align heading when div is position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I want to have the heading text vertically aligned in the middle of the div, currently it is pushed down using margin-top but this is causing inconsistencies when the titles are longer and overflow onto a second line.

Please see the sample here:
http://ryconbg.jaffewebsites.com.au/our-company/sustainability-and-energy-efficiency/

**HTML**

```
    <div id="page-featured" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important; overflow: hidden; background-size: cover !important; background-position: center !important;"></div>

    <div id="page-overlay">
        <div id="page-titles">
            <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#page-overlay, #page-featured {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

#page-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    z-index: 100;
    color: #FFF;
}

#page-titles {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

#page-titles h1,
#page-titles p {
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, correction - It is currently being pushed down with top:40% rather than margin-top

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add details. Thanks.

Comment: why is vertical-align:center not working? why are you using margins to centre to your text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `transform:translate` (CSS3) to vertical align

Read more about here: http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

**CSS**

```
#page-overlay, #page-featured {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
#page-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 95px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    z-index: 100;
    color: #FFF;
}
#page-titles {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
#page-titles h1, #page-titles p {
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yv5q4gvm/31/)**

Answer (score 0):

**If you know the height of the element you're trying to center** (no need for its container's height), you could use absolute positioning and negative margins to achieve this. Change the `top` value on `#page-titles h1` to `50%` and then substract `margin-top` by half of its height, which in your case would be `margin-top: -24px`. I made a fiddle to demonstrate this method: http://jsfiddle.net/8s1g7ws0/ You can see it works for horizontal centering as well.

The idea is that `top: 50%` makes the element *begin* in the middle of its container, so it's not actually centered. Then, by moving it half of its height back up, we match up both elements' middle points.

**If you don't know the height of your element**, you could display your container element as `table-cell`, then you can use `vertical-align: middle` to center what's inside. Here are the changes you need to make in your case:

- Add `display: table` to `#page-overlay`
- Remove `position: absolute` from `#page-titles h1`.
- Add `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: middle` to `#page-titles`.

[Browser support for display: table](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table)